# logger.error("string",e) Not working in scala-play while using future and async

Tags: scala, logging, playframework-2.0, error-logging

I am getting the error 
for logger.error ( " string ", e )

Expression of type unit does'nt conform to expected type _U

The code is below

```
object DataFormatController extends Controller {

  val logger: Logger = Logger("Data Format Controller")
  val dataFormatDao = new DataFormatDao(Global.cassandraSession, Global.getKeyspace)

  def listFormats(companyId: Option[String], userId: Option[String]) = Action.async(parse.anyContent){
    import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext
     implicit request =>
       val json = Json.obj("company_id" -> companyId, "user_id" -> userId)
       val reqResult = json.validate[ListDataFormatRequest](listFormatReads)


  reqResult match {
    case s: JsSuccess[ListDataFormatRequest] =>
      val formatsFuture = dataFormatDao.findAllAsync(s.get.companyId).map(f => {
          val res = f.map(x => {
            new ListDataFormat(x.format, x.id)
          })
        Ok(Json.obj("status" -> 1, "data" -> Json.toJson(res)))
      })

      formatsFuture.recover {
        case e: Throwable => {
          BadRequest(Json.toJson(Response(0, errorMessage = Some(e.getMessage))))
          logger.error("asd",e)
        }
      }
    case e: JsError => Future(BadRequest(Json.toJson(
      Response(0, errorMessage = Some(Utils.convertToReadableMessage(e))))))
  }
}
}
```

I want to log the error from this !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `recover` on a future, you need to return a value of the same (ish) type as the original future.

```
  formatsFuture.recover {
    case e: Throwable => {
      BadRequest(Json.toJson(Response(0, errorMessage = Some(e.getMessage))))
      logger.error("asd",e)
    }
  }
```

The last value in the block is the return value.  Since that's a call to `logger.error`, the compiler thinks you're returning a value of `Unit`, which does not satisfy the requirements of `recover`.

The order should be switched so that `BadRequest` is returned:

```
  formatsFuture.recover {
    case e: Throwable => {
      logger.error("asd",e)
      BadRequest(Json.toJson(Response(0, errorMessage = Some(e.getMessage))))          
    }
  }
```